# Dimension of variety Z(xy-zt)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

In my algebraic geometry course my professor claims without additional comment or proof that the affine variety $Z(xy-zt)$ in $A^4$ is irreducible and has dimension $3$.

Is there a clear way to see or argue this? I'm really not sure how to picture what this variety would look like in my mind...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Krull's height theorem, plus the fact that in a UFD an ideal is prime iff it is generated by an irreducible element (then show that equation does not factor). These are likely duplicates, but I don't have an obvious candidate in mind right now.

Comment: The coordinate ring is $K(x,y,z,xy/z]$, an integral domain. Quite clear that it has dimension $\le \dim K[x,y,z]= 3$ and the chain $(z-1),(z-1,x),(z-1,x,y)$ gives dimension $\ge 3$.